# Java Script parseFloat() unexpected decimal places

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, numbers

Why when I am cast this string "2019275.159999999916180968" to number, or when used parseFloat(str). I'm always get result "2019275.16". Why it remove extra decimal places that provided in the string? And how can i keep number of decimal places, without rounding it to 2 decimal places in this case?

Amount of decimal places in the string is dynamical.

Comment: Because floating point numbers don't have that much precision, and at the level of precision it has, the two numbers are equivalent.

Comment: but when after parsing I'm make 2019275.16.toFixed(18) I'm got exactly same value that I am needed - "2019275.159999999916180968". So why it cant make it at once?

Comment: Hi, try to use this :  https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Because when you don't specify the precision with `toFixed()`, it uses the least precision that produces an equivalent internal representation.

Comment: `2019275.159999999916180968 == 2019275.16` is `true`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/

Comment: Could you provide more details about how you're using the number? It might be easier for people to suggest / demonstrate an approach to the problem if you do.

Comment: @BenStephens I have string "2019275.159999999912345" i want to put it into database as double with exactly the same amount of decimal places. So i convert it into the number with Number("2019275.159999999912345") or parseFloat("2019275.159999999912345") and put into database. And inside database i have value 2019275.16

Comment: What sort of database is it? What's the column datatype that you're storing it into? Do you really need to convert from string to number before storing it in the database?

Comment: @BenStephens, NodeJs application parse file with strings like "2019275.159999999912345" (STRING). 
After parsing, inside application, we should convert that string into Number and make some Math calculations, for example STRING + 1, end after that, store calculated value into MongoDB in column with Decimal128 type. 

After all of that i have value 2019276.16 (STRING +1) stored in database. But expected: 2019276.159999999912345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth investigating a library like [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) to help with this. e.g.:

```js
Decimal.set({ precision: 24 }); // The default of 20 is not big enough for the number below so you may need to adjust this

let a = new Decimal('2019275.159999999912345');
a = a.plus(1);

let b = new Decimal('2019275.159999999912345').plus(1);
let c = Decimal.add('2019275.159999999912345', 1);

console.log(a, b, c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/9.0.0/decimal.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed() method after parseFloat() otherwise it will return least precision equivalent to internal representation

```javascript
parseFloat("2019275.159999999916180968").toFixed(18)
```

Comment: parseFloat("2019275.159999999912345678").toFixed(18) is also "2019275.159999999916180968"

Comment: So, does we have any way to store all decimal places after "2019275.159999999912345678"(for example) converting